# Getting parts of a repetitive string in C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, indexof

Extracting parts of a string is a common question, but here the string content, e.g. ' "main\":{\"temp\": ' is repetitive:

```
string test = "{\"cod\":\"200\",\"message\":0,\"cnt\":40,\"list\":[{\"dt\":1576810800,\"main\":{\"temp\":288.19,\"feels_like\":284.44,\"temp_min\":288.19,\"temp_max\":291.53,\"{\"dt\":1576821600,\"main\":{ \"temp\":283.97,\"feels_like\":281.56,\"temp_min\":283.97,\"temp_max\":286.47,\"pressure\":1007,\"sea_level\":1007,\"grnd_level\":997,\"humidity\":93,\"temp_kf\":-2.5},\"weather\":[{\"id\":501,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"moderate rai\",\"icon\":\"10d\"}],\"clouds\":{\"all\":90},\"wind\"";
```

Using

```
string s = test.Substring(test.IndexOf("\"main\":{\"temp\":") + 15);
```

I get

```
288.19,"feels_like":284.44,,"temp_min":288.19,"temp_max":291.53,"{"dt":157682160
0,"main":{ "temp":283.97,"feels_like":281.56,"temp_min":283.97,"temp_max":286.47
,"pressure":1007,"sea_level":1007,"grnd_level":997,"humidity":93,"temp_kf":-2.5}
,"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],
"clouds":{"all":90},"wind"
```

instead of

```
288.19
```

Any clue what command would help? Should be something that can be adapted to ' "temp_max" ' or ' "pressure" '.

Cheers

Comment: How are you getting that string? It looks like JSON that's been damaged. If it weren't damaged, you could use a JSON serializer and then query the object hierarchy to get the "main temp" array you want... but until it's valid JSON, that won't work.

Comment: This sounds like [an X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain where the `test` string is coming from and what you are trying to do? We may be able to provide a better solution that simply searching a string

Comment: I would expect that the original string was valid JSON, but an error crept in when it was translated to C#.

Comment: When using `SubString()` the first parameter is the strart index. You should apply a second parameter for the length you want.

Comment: Regex is always a good option to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mohammed, here's the working code spitting out all tempeatures:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace ConsoleApp2
{

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<MyList> list { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyList
    {
        public Main main { get; set; }
    }

    public class Main
    {
        public double temp { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ACCESSING ...");
                string test = client.DownloadString("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Auckland,NZ&APPID=45c3e583468bf450fc17026d6734507e");
                //string test = "{\"cod\":\"200\",\"message\":0,\"cnt\":40,\"list\":[{\"dt\":1576810800,\"main\":{\"temp\":288.19,\"feels_like\":284.44,\"temp_min\":288.19,\"temp_max\":291.53,\"{\"dt\":1576821600,\"main\":{ \"temp\":283.97,\"feels_like\":281.56,\"temp_min\":283.97,\"temp_max\":286.47,\"pressure\":1007,\"sea_level\":1007,\"grnd_level\":997,\"humidity\":93,\"temp_kf\":-2.5},\"weather\":[{\"id\":501,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"moderate rai\",\"icon\":\"10d\"}],\"clouds\":{\"all\":90},\"wind\"";

                var myobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(test); //test is JSON response as string 

                foreach (var item in myobject.list)
                {
                    var temp = item.main.temp;
                    Console.WriteLine(temp);


                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//classes.cs
public class RootObject
{
    public List<MyList> list { get; set; }
}

public class MyList
{
    public Main main { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public double temp { get; set; }
}

//API client
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var myobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(test); //test is JSON response as string 

foreach(var item in myobject.list){
  var temp = item.main.temp;
}

//Hope it helps
```

Comment: Cool, that helps with that. Is there a way to put all "main temp" in an array and then I access [x] of it? That way I could do this for all values and the first is always the current and [x+1] is predicted etc. Thanks!

Comment: Cleanest and fastest option is Deserialize JSON string to object and get the array.. I will put some addition code in my reply

Comment: have you tried test.Split("main {")… This will split your string and create a new row into an array whenever it comes across the string... in this case "main {" -- or whatever context section that works best for repetative you know will be in each instance.

Comment: If you prefer string manipulation over JSON.. then you can try RegEx.. `Regex.Matches(test, "main {", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

Comment: Thanks Mohamed. I am an absolute noob with programing. I appreciate your help with JSON!

Comment: No worries.. can you send me the full `test` test string to convert to JSON object?

Comment: this is it: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Auckland,NZ&APPID=45c3e583468bf450fc17026d6734507e "raw" view - thx a lot man, apprechiated! :)

Comment: Changed answer.. let me know if you have questions

Comment: Thanks! I got some errors. I copied the public class within the namespace and added the Json to the references. When putting the code starting with "var object" in my Main it says 'var', list' and 'item' do not exists in the current context :( see: https://i.postimg.cc/VLzLjSGf/Clipboard01.png

Comment: I replaced object by myobject and list by myobject.list .. this should solve compile errors

Comment: Thanks heaps Mohamend. I copied that in my code and "item" seems to still cause issues. see: https://i.postimg.cc/pr4wc6QM/Clipboard01.png

Comment: Please put foreach(var item instead of for(item

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
var regexGroups = Regex.Matches(test, "\"main\" ?: ?{ ?\"temp\" ?: ?(\\d+\\.\\d+)")
    .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
```

You can get all `\"main\":{\"temp\":` values.